# How can I get the video id of the top youtube query result?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api, spotify, youtube-javascript-api

All of my coding experience is in lower level systems but I wanted to learn some html/js stuff so i'm pretty noob - you might need to spell things out for me sometimes.

I have three files, search.js, query.js, and index.html

search.js: a modified version of youtube data API. I really just want the video id of the top result from the search. Eventually I will use that video id to play a music video in a Spotify app.

```
// Called automatically when JavaScript client library is loaded.
function onClientLoad() {
    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', onYouTubeApiLoad);
}

// Called automatically when YouTube API interface is loaded (see line 9).
function onYouTubeApiLoad() {
    // This API key is intended for use only in this lesson.
    // See http://goo.gl/PdPA1 to get a key for your own applications.
    gapi.client.setApiKey('MY API KEY HERE');
}

// Search for a specified string.
function search() {
  var q = document.getElementById('videoQuery');
  var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
    q: q,
    part: 'snippet'
    type: 'video'
  });

  // run the search function and save the video id DOM
  request.execute(function(response) {
    var result_id = (response.items[0]).id;

    // result_id now holds the video id that we need to play. 
    document.getElementById('video_id').value = result_id;
  });
}
```

query.js: This file i wrote from scratch so please let me know if I'm doing things wrong here. I'm constructing a search query string from information about the currently playing track. The Spotify app API is being used heavily here.

```
require([
    '$api/models'
], function(models) {
    'use strict';

    var youtubeQuery = function() {
        // We generate the youtube query by getting the track name and album name. 
        var videoQuery = models.player.track.name;
            videoQuery += " ";
            videoQuery += models.player.track.album.name;

        document.getElementById('videoQuery').value = videoQuery;
    };

    exports.youtubeQuery = youtubeQuery;  
});
```

index.html: I added the html code from the youtube data API example to the spotify boilerplate html file. I don't actually want the users to see a search box since the search should be automated. So there should be a way to hide things in html pretty easily. Eventually I'll be adding a youtube player that occupies the allowed area for a spotify app.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Vidify</title>
    <!-- Include the stylesheets you need for the Views components -->
    <!-- See https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/views/1.0/ -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="$views/css/image.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="$views/css/list.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="$views/css/buttons.css">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="$views/css/throbber.css"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1></h1>

    <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>    
    <div id="ytapiplayer">
    You need Flash player 8+ and JavaScript enabled to view this video.
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var URL = "http://www.youtube.com/v/";
        URL += document.getElementById('video_id');
        URL += "?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&version=3"

    var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
    var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };
    swfobject.embedSWF(URL,"ytapiplayer", "425", "356", "8", null, null, params, atts);

    </script>




    <div id="buttons">
      <label> <input id="videoQuery" value="" type="text"/><button id="search-button" disabled onclick="search()">Search</button></label>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="auth.js"></script>
    <script src="search.js"></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

**My questions:**

I'm confused how to get everything working together but it would really help to know how I could just get the video ID string of the result from the youtube search. Also, is my js and html correct for feeding the query into the search.js file?

Relevant API links:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference
https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/guidelines/developer/

Comment: come on I know someone out there has used the youtube api